# toggleClass works just once

Tags: javascript, jquery

my toggleClass functions only works just once as I know it has to be works forever - rotated and I added if else condition my jquery codes get classname

my html structure;

```
<div class="form-elements">
<input type="button" name="d5" class="d5"  />
<input type="button" name="d4" class="d4" />
<input type="button" name="d3" class="d3"  />
<input type="button" name="d2" class="d2" />
<input type="button" name="d1" class="d1" />                     
</div>
```

css documents

```
.d1 {

  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1.png);
  border: 0;
 display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d1_pasif {
    background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d2 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d2_pasif { background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2_pasif.png);

  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d3 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d3_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d4 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4.png);
  border: 0;
 display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d4_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
.d5 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
.d5_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

and this is my js documents

```
$(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function() {

  var el = $(this).attr("class");
    if($(this).hasClass("d1")){
    $(".d1").toggleClass('d1 d1_pasif');

}else if($(this).hasClass("d2")){

 $(".d2").toggleClass('d2 d2_pasif');

}else if($(this).hasClass("d3")){

  $(".d3").toggleClass('d3 d3_pasif');

}else if($(this).hasClass("d4")){

  $(".d4").toggleClass('d4 d4_pasif');  

}
    else if($(this).hasClass("d5")){

  $(".d5").toggleClass('d5 d5_pasif');

    }
  return false;
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much easier way to do this, add the classes as

```
.d1 {
    background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1.png);
     ...
}

.d1.pasif {
    background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1_pasif.png);
    ....
}
```

where you change only what's supposed to change, not all the styles, and just do

```
$(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('pasif');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/1dr44ctn/1/)

Comment: its working very well but there is something I understand this is not work my web page but in demo page works perfectly

[my demo link](http://www.anitur.com.tr/deneme-otel-liste)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
 $(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass($(this).attr('name')+'_pasif');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function () {

        var el = $(this).attr("name");
        if (el == "d1") {
            $(this).toggleClass('d1_pasif');

        } else if (el == "d2") {

            $(this).toggleClass('d2_pasif');

        } else if (el == "d3") {

            $(this).toggleClass('d3_pasif');

        } else if (el == "d4") {

            $(this).toggleClass('d4_pasif');

        } else if (el == "d5") {

            $(this).toggleClass('d5_pasif');

        }
        return false;
    });
```

As it working first time because classes d1,d2 etc present when dom is loaded but once you use ToggleClass d1,d2 is removed from button.So Jquery selector will not work when you click second time.

Comment: As it working first time because classes d1,d2 etc present when dom is loaded but once you use ToggleClass d1,d2 is removed from button.So Jquery selector will not work second time click.

Answer (score 0):

About this?

```js
$(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function(e) {
      var el = $(this).attr("name");
      switch(el){
          case 'd1': $(this).toggleClass('d1_pasif'); break;
          case 'd2': $(this).toggleClass('d2_pasif'); break;
          case 'd3': $(this).toggleClass('d3_pasif'); break;
          case 'd4': $(this).toggleClass('d4_pasif'); break;
          case 'd5': $(this).toggleClass('d5_pasif'); break;
      }
});
```

```css
.d1 {

  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1.png);
  border: 0;
 display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d1_pasif {
    background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d2 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d2_pasif { background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2_pasif.png);

  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d3 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d3_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d4 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4.png);
  border: 0;
 display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d4_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
.d5 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
.d5_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-elements">
<input type="button" name="d5" class="d5"  />
<input type="button" name="d4" class="d4" />
<input type="button" name="d3" class="d3"  />
<input type="button" name="d2" class="d2" />
<input type="button" name="d1" class="d1" />                     
</div>
```

ref: [.toggleClass() JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle just the `pasif` class not `d1 d1_pasif`- because `d1` exists from default and when you toggle it first time you actually remove it and insert just `d1_pasif` => so it cannot work

```js
$(".form-elements input[type='button']").on("click", function() {

  var el = $(this).attr("class");
    if($(this).hasClass("d1")){
    $(".d1").toggleClass('d1_pasif');

}else if($(this).hasClass("d2")){

 $(".d2").toggleClass('d2_pasif');

}else if($(this).hasClass("d3")){

  $(".d3").toggleClass('d3_pasif');

}else if($(this).hasClass("d4")){

  $(".d4").toggleClass('d4_pasif');  

}
    else if($(this).hasClass("d5")){

  $(".d5").toggleClass('d5_pasif');

    }
  return false; 
});
```

```css
.d1 {

  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1.png);
  border: 0;
 display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d1_pasif {
    background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d1_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d2 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d2_pasif { background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d2_pasif.png);

  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d3 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d3_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d3_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d4 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4.png);
  border: 0;
 display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.d4_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d4_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
.d5 {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
.d5_pasif {
  background: url(https://anitur.streamprovider.net/images/otel-filtre/d5_pasif.png);
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-elements">
<input type="button" name="d5" class="d5"  />
<input type="button" name="d4" class="d4" />
<input type="button" name="d3" class="d3"  />
<input type="button" name="d2" class="d2" />
<input type="button" name="d1" class="d1" />                     
</div>
```